# Logistic Proof in TFL

Tags: logic

[image]

Cannot seem to figure this one out, my structure might be completely wrong, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\fitch#1#2{~~~~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}$

You have most of the proof, but there should not be a second subproof.

Do not assume $\lnot A$.   Rather this is derived by negation introduction.

$$\fitch{~~1.~A\to B}{\fitch{~~2.~\lnot(\lnot A\lor B)}{\fitch{~~3.~A}{~~4.~B\hspace{12ex}{\to}\mathsf E~3,1\\~~5.~\lnot A\lor B\hspace{6ex}\lor\mathsf I~4\\~~6.~\bot\hspace{12ex}{\lnot}\mathsf E~5,2}\\~~7.~\lnot A\hspace{15ex}{\lnot}\mathsf I~3{-}6\quad\bigstar\\[1ex]~~8.~\lnot A\lor B\hspace{10ex}\lor\mathsf I~7\\~~9.~\bot\hspace{16ex}{\lnot}\mathsf E~8,2}\\10.~\lnot A\lor B\hspace{15ex}\mathsf{RAA}~2{-}9}$$

---

Note, however, that there is an alternative proof using the Law of Excluded Middle, rather than reduction to absurdity.

$$\fitch{~~1.~A\to B}{\fitch{~~2.~A}{~~3.~B\hspace{15ex}{\to}\mathsf E~2,1\\~~4.~\lnot A\lor B\hspace{9ex}\lor\mathsf I~3}\\\fitch{~~5.~\lnot A}{~~6.~\lnot A\lor B\hspace{10ex}\lor\mathsf I~5}\\~~7.~\lnot A\lor B\hspace{15ex}\mathsf{LEM}~2{-}4,5{-}6}$$

Does your system implement some form of LEM?  (It may, for instance, take the form of declaring $A\lor\lnot A$ then using disjunction elimination. So adjust to your system's taste.)

Comment: Thank you so much! the first one passed! I have another question of proofing I am going to post it right now, if you have time please help me take a look. Appreciate that!